# How to add a custom button in the ModeBar of a plotly graph using python dash?

Tags: javascript, python, button, plotly, plotly-dash

I have this simple dash application that displays an image using plotly:

```
import dash
import plotly.express as px
from dash import html, dcc
from skimage import data

img = data.chelsea()
fig = px.imshow(img)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id = "graph-pic", className="graph-pic", figure=fig)
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True,use_reloader=True)
```

I need to add a custom button to the graph's ModeBar. I know it's possible considering [this](https://plotly.com/javascript/configuration-options/#add-buttons-to-modebar) documentation but the example doesn't include python.

I already have this java script under an *assets* folder that creates the button for me. But how do I pass that `config` to my graph back in python?

```
var config = {
    modeBarButtonsToAdd: [
        {
            name: 'button1',
            icon: Plotly.Icons.pencil,
            direction: 'up',
            click: function(gd) {alert('button1')}
        }]
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get any help or resolve this?